# Redirect the request through Apache to another (Weblogic) server having port number

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

In our server machine, we have two server software: Apache on port 80 and Weblogic on port 7001.

We want to redirect all requests coming to Apache under the subdirectory TRACDISWEB http://x.x.x.x/TRACDISWEB/ to  http://x.x.x.x:7001/TRACDISWEB/

How can I do this?

**Update:**

In another similar [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/201196/apache-port-redirect) someone asked the following redirection:

jira.mydomain.com to jira.mydomain.com:8181

The accepted answer is this:

```
<VirtualHost jira.mydomain.com:*>
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://jira.mydomain.com:8181/
ProxyPassReverse / http://jira.mydomain.com:8181/
ServerName jira.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

So, taking this as an example, should I write something like this:

```
<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:7001/TRACDISWEB/*>
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://x.x.x.x:7001/TRACDISWEB/
ProxyPassReverse / http://x.x.x.x:7001/TRACDISWEB/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

> So, taking this as an example, should I write something like this:

no, it should be written like

```
<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:80>
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyRequests Off

   ProxyPass /TRACDISWEB/ http://x.x.x.x:7001/TRACDISWEB/
   ProxyPassReverse /TRACDISWEB/ http://x.x.x.x:7001/TRACDISWEB/
   ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into Apache's mod_proxy and the proxypass functionality.